# Java: Getting this: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, arrays

Expected output array with values : 1, 1

Actual Output get error : "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0"

I'm getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` exception and I don't know why. Please Help me out.

Here is my Java file in which, I've problem:

```
public class Solution {

//compare two arrays and if the value of any element is of a particular index is greater than the other array element, return the value as 1.

    static int[] solve(int a0, int a1, int a2, int b0, int b1, int b2) {

        int[] a = { a0, a1, a2 };
        int[] b = { b0, b1, b2 };
        int[] r = {};
        int y = 1;

        for (int x = 0; x <= a.length; x++) {

            for (int i = 0; i <= a.length; i++) {
                if (a[i] > b[i]) {

                    r[x] = y;

                }
                if (b[i] > a[i]) {

                    System.out.println(r);
                    r[x] = y;

                }
                if (b[i] == a[i]) {

                    System.out.println("");

                }
            }
        }
        return r;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        int[] result = solve(5, 6, 7, 3, 6, 10);

    }
}
```

Getting an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` in this code.

Thanks.

Comment: replace `<=` with `<` at the `for loops`

Comment: Hi Unnati, could you rephrase the title of your question, so that it's easier to understand your problem?

Answer (score 1):

You use `<=` as comparison operator. In Java, we always use `<` to loop over arrays. Replacing your comparison operator in the for-loops should circumvent the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: I changed it to < but it still gives the same output : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0